# Landscape Server - SMTP Configuration

Tags: email, landscape

I am still rather new to linux, but have set up a landscape server (free, on premise) to manage a number of other Ubuntu 16.04 Servers.

During the install, I didn't specify any SMTP details, hence now my landscape solution cannot email invites for new user accounts.

My question is, How do I / can I reconfigure the landscape SMTP settings, now the server has been configured, or will I need to remove and re-install landscape?

Comment: How did you install `landscape`? Would `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` help?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the answer was to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```